# MahApps - Alterar o Style de um Tile com Binding em uma propriedade de uma classe - MVVM

Tags: wpf

Estou criando um menu dinâmico usando `Tiles` (MahApps). Tenho dois tipos de `Tiles` que posso utilizar: *LargeTileStyle* e *SmallTileStyle*. Para isso, tenho uma função que me permite passar o nome do `Style` via parâmetro e setar a propriedade `Style`, quando o `Tile` for criado.

Criação dos `Tiles`:

```
this.Tile.Add(
   new TileItem() 
   { 
       Icon = new PackIconFontAwesome() 
       { 
         Kind = PackIconFontAwesomeKind.Angellist 
       }, 
       Text = "Usuários", 
       Style = "LargeTileStyle", 
       Background = "Green", 
       NavigationDestination = new Uri("Views/UsuarioList.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) 
    }
);

this.Tile.Add(
    new TileItem() 
    { 
        Icon = new PackIconFontAwesome() 
        { 
           Kind = PackIconFontAwesomeKind.Apple 
        }, 
        Text = "Clientes", 
        Style = "SmallTileStyle", 
        Background = "Blue", 
        NavigationDestination = new Uri("Views/ClienteList.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) 
    }
);
```

Classe `TileItem`:

```
internal class TileItem : BindableBase
    {
        private object _icon;
        private string _text;
        private string _style;
        private string _background;
        private DelegateCommand _command;
        private Uri _navigationDestination;


        public object Icon
        {
            get { return this._icon; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._icon, value); }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return this._text; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._text, value); }
        }

        public string Style
        {
            get { return this._style; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._style, value); }
        }

        public string Background
        {
            get { return this._background; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._background, value); }
        }

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return this._command; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._command, (DelegateCommand)value); }
        }

        public Uri NavigationDestination
        {
            get { return this._navigationDestination; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._navigationDestination, value); }
        }

        public bool IsNavigation => this._navigationDestination != null;
    }
```

O problema é que no bloco abaixo, quando eu faço um `Binding` para setar a propriedade `Style`, não dá certo, pois ele não consegue setar com os nomes que passo por parâmetro. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Style:

```
<ResourceDictionary>          

            <Style x:Key="LargeTileStyle" TargetType="Controls:Tile">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="125" />
                <Setter Property="TitleFontSize" Value="16" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="SmallTileStyle" TargetType="Controls:Tile">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="147" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="125" />
                <Setter Property="TitleFontSize" Value="16" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

Layout da minha Window:

```
<Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tile}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>                    
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:Tile
                        Title="{Binding Text}"
                        controls:ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.TileClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        HorizontalTitleAlignment="Left"
                        Background="{Binding Background}"
                        Style="{Binding Style}"
                        TiltFactor="2">
                        <Image  Width="60"
                            Height="60"/>
                        <!--<Source="{Binding OmsConnectionTypeId, Converter={StaticResource ConnectionTypeToIconConverter}}"/>-->
                    </controls:Tile>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>       
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acessar um `style` ou algum `resource` específico da sua aplicação, você pode buscá-lo através do nome, usando o método `FindResource()`. Para utilizar esse método, a sua classe deve pertencer ao `FrameworkElement`, como por exemplo, o **code behind** (*.cs*) de uma Window.

```
Style smallTileStyle = (Style)FindResource("SmallTileStyle"); 
Style largeTileStyle = (Style)FindResource("LargeTileStyle");
```

Altere a sua classe `TileItem` e modifique o tipo da propriedade *Style* para o tipo `Style`:

```
internal class TileItem : BindableBase
{
    private object _icon;
    private string _text;
    private Style _style;
    private string _background;
    private DelegateCommand _command;
    private Uri _navigationDestination;


    public object Icon
    {
        get { return this._icon; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._icon, value); }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return this._text; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._text, value); }
    }

    public Style Style
    {
        get { return this._style; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._style, value); }
    }

    public string Background
    {
        get { return this._background; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._background, value); }
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return this._command; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._command, (DelegateCommand)value); }
    }

    public Uri NavigationDestination
    {
        get { return this._navigationDestination; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._navigationDestination, value); }
    }

    public bool IsNavigation => this._navigationDestination != null;
}

nomeDoSeuObjeto.Style = smallTileStyle;
```

No momento de criação dos seus Tiles, utilize o código informado anteriormente para buscar os styles desejados e atribua ao seu objeto TileItem:

```
// Busca o style nos Resources (App.xaml)
Style smallTileStyle = (Style)FindResource("SmallTileStyle"); 
Style largeTileStyle = (Style)FindResource("LargeTileStyle");

// Atribui o style nos tiles criados
this.Tile.Add(
   new TileItem() 
   { 
       Icon = new PackIconFontAwesome() 
       { 
         Kind = PackIconFontAwesomeKind.Angellist 
       }, 
       Text = "Usuários", 
       Style = largeTileStyle, 
       Background = "Green", 
       NavigationDestination = new Uri("Views/UsuarioList.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) 
    }
);

this.Tile.Add(
    new TileItem() 
    { 
        Icon = new PackIconFontAwesome() 
        { 
           Kind = PackIconFontAwesomeKind.Apple 
        }, 
        Text = "Clientes", 
        Style = smallTileStyle, 
        Background = "Blue", 
        NavigationDestination = new Uri("Views/ClienteList.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) 
    }
);
```

No seu XAML faça o bind para a propriedade criada:

```
<Controls:Tile 
     Title="TileOne" 
     Style="{Binding Style}" 
     Margin="133,539,666,21" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Perozzo, mas não entendi a parte onde vc diz: "Para utilizar esse método, a sua classe deve pertencer ao FrameworkElement, como por exemplo, o code behind (.cs) de uma Window." Não sei como isso funciona...

Comment: Eu tentei, colocar no método Load da Page, mas não funcionou...

Comment: Isso teria que ficar dentro de alguma função?

Comment: O que não funcionou? Deu erro ou simplesmente não funcionou? Se não funcionou é por causa do seu binding. Como disse na outra resposta, o binding da propriedade Style pode mudar dependendo da forma como arquitetou seu app para o binding. Eu testei essa solução antes de publicar a resposta e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Ficou sublinhado de vermelho o "FindResource"... Não entendi pq setar minha property Style com smallTileStyle: nomeDoSeuObjeto.Style = smallTileStyle; e se eu precisar setar com LargeTileStyle?

Comment: Se ficou sublinhado de vermelho é porque você está utilizando no lugar errado. Em qual classe tu colocou isso? Se colocou na classe TileItem não irá funcionar, pois como mencionado a sua classe deve ser um FrameworkElement. Sobre o smallTileStyle é apenas um exemplo, se tu quiser utilizar o largeTileStyle, tu atribui ele ao invés do outro. Na hora de criar seu objeto TileItem, tu coloca ou o SmallTileStyle ou o LargeTileStyle na propriedade Style.

Comment: Em qual classe tu cria os Tiles? Ali em cima tu mencionou a "Criação dos Tiles". Em qual classe tu faz isso?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63920/discussion-between-perozzo-and-jalber-romano).

Comment: Classe TileItem

Comment: Entra no chat pra resolvermos logo isso.